# How to detect which knob was changed in ionic 4 ion-range with duallKnobs?

Tags: ionic4

I'm using ionic 4 and ion-range with dualKnobs set to true. And I need to detect which knob (left or right) was updated and get its value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of hacky approach but it works.

Template-

```
<ion-range id="dual-range" dual-knobs pin color="dark" (ionChange)="knobChange($event)" (ionBlur)="afterChange($event)">
  <ion-icon slot="start" size="small" name="brush"></ion-icon>
  <ion-icon slot="end" name="brush"></ion-icon>
</ion-range>
```

TypeScript file -

```
...

export class DemoPage implements OnInit{

  upperValue: number;
  lowerValue: number;
  changedKnob: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lowerValue = 33;
    this.upperValue = 60;
    const dualRange = document.querySelector('#dual-range') as HTMLIonRangeElement;
    dualRange.value = { lower: this.lowerValue, upper: this.upperValue };
  }

  knobChange(range: CustomEvent<RangeChangeEventDetail>) {
    if (range.detail.value['lower'] !== this.lowerValue) {
      this.lowerValue = range.detail.value['lower'];
      this.changedKnob = 'lower';
    } else if (range.detail.value['upper'] !== this.upperValue) {
      this.upperValue = range.detail.value['upper'];
      this.changedKnob = 'upper';
    }
  }

  afterChange() {
    if (this.changedKnob === 'upper') {
      console.log('upper is changed. value : ' + this.upperValue);
    } else {
      console.log('lower is changed. value : ' + this.lowerValue);
    }

  }

}
```